# $L_2$ norm of a matrix using Schur-Jordan decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra, singular-values

> Prove that for $A \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$, $\|A\|_2 = σ_{\max}$ using the Schur-Jordan decomposition of the appropriate matrix.

I have to apply the Schur-Jordan decomposition on $AA^T$ since it is symmetric, and because from it, we get the singular values.

So $AA^T = QDQ^T$, where $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix, and $D$ is a diagonal matrix with diagonal entries the eigenvalues of $A$.

So $||AA^T||_2 = ||QDQ^T||_2 \leq ||QD||_2 × ||Q^T||_2 = ||D||_2 × ||Q^T||_2$ (since $Q$ is orthogonal, then $||QD||_2 = ||D||_2$, and $||Q||_2 = 1$).

Hence, $||AA^T||_2 \leq max|\lambda_i| × 1$, since $||D||_2$ is the max of the its eigenvalues. But how to continue from there to reach what's required? I know that the singualr values of $A$ are the square root of the eigenvalues of $AA^T$. Any help please?

Comment: The singular values of $A$ are the square roots of the eigenvalues of $AA^\top$, that is,your $\sqrt{\lambda_i}$. Also $\|A\|_2^2=\|AA^\top\|$ is the largest eigenvalue in $D$.

Comment: So, is it $||A||_2^2 = ||AA^T|| = ||QDQ^T|| \leq ||QD|| × ||Q^T|| = ||D|| × 1 = max|\lambda_i|$. And hence, $||A||_2 = \sqrt{\lambda_i} = \sigma_{max} $?

Comment: Actually $\|QDQ^\top\|=\|D\|$ when $D$ is diagonal, so $\|A\|=\sqrt{\lambda_{max}}=\sigma_{max}$ directly.